# Symfony calls unwanted constructor of my class when running command

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, symfony4, autowired

Symfony 4.4, I want to keep some of my classes as "simple/pure" PHP class = no service and use just "new MyClass(..)" to initialize it inside my code.
What's more important, I want to have constructor with my own parameters and prevent DI to inject parameters automatically (even if NULL is allowed). In other word, keep autowire+DI everywhere, but exclude selected classes.

Problem is, when I have such a class, it's called automatically everytime I run "php bin/console ...".
I don't want such a behavior and I want to prevent running constructor of MyClass or any other pure PHP class when running bin/console.

Pure PHP MyClass inside of "src/Classes/" folder:

```
<?php

namespace App\Classes;

use App\Entity\MyEntity;

class MyClass {
    public function __construct(?MyEntity $myEntity) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

It's initialized in both, Service and Command as:

```
$this->myClass = new MyClass($myEntity);
```

I also configured exclusion in "services.yaml":

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true

    App\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude: [
            '../src/Classes/'
            , '../src/DependencyInjection/'
            , '../src/Entity/'
            , '../src/Tests/'
            , '../src/Kernel.php'
        ]
```

My case is very similar as discussed here: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/25946

But I'm not initializing my "pure" PHP class in Command constructor. I'm using "new" keyword later inside my code.
Here is my Command example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

use App\Classes\MyClass;

class MyCommand extends Command {
    
    private $kernel;
    private $em;
    
    public function __construct(KernelInterface $kernel, EntityManagerInterface $em) {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->krenel = $kernel;
        $this->em = $em;
    }
    
    protected function configure() {
        $this->setName('app:myCommand');
    }
    
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {
        ...
        $this->myClass = new MyClass($myEntity);
        ...
    }
}
```

How to solve? Thank you.

Comment: So how do you know it's being called called automatically?  The exclude change you made should prevent that from happening.  Maybe you need a clear cache?  Are you getting an error concerning the constructor argument?